# Why is the notification coming 9 hours late?

Tags: notifications, calendar, google-calendar, reminders

I created a full-day event in my Google Calendar using my Android-phone.
The notification is set to "7 AM on the same day".
But for some reason, it notifies me consistently at 4 PM (4 minutes ago in the screenshot below).

I did already delete the entry without effect.

What can I do to get the notification at the time displayed?

My timezone-settings seem to be correct: the phone displays the correct time and notifications for normal (non-full-day) events show up at the correct time. Also all events that are synchronized from my Exchange-account are displayed at the correct time.

The device is a Hauwei P20 Pro with a stock-rom.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you state the timezone of the device (and if it's okay with you, your current location's timezone if it's different than the device's)? I have experienced a similar issue related to how all-day events are created while developing a calendar app, so I want to confirm if that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: The phone runs on the same timezone I am currently located: middle European time (Berlin).